# ADSystemInfo.UserName bstr to string

Tags: vbscript, bstr

I need to execute a logon script where I need to check if the user belongs to a OU specific.

I get the DN:

```
Dim objSysInfo, objUser
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUserDN = objSysInfo.UserName
```

And then I use the `InStr` function to search the OU specific but alway get 0 as the position although the string to compare exists in the DN.

I think that the problem is that `objSysInfo.UserName` retrieves a BSTR data and I need to convert to string but I don't know how.

This is the complete code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim objSysInfo, objUser

Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

strUserDN = objSysInfo.UserName
WScript.Echo "DN: " & strUserDN

ouZaragoza="OU=Zaragoza"
ouGeneral="OU=General"
WScript.Echo InStr("OU=Informática",strUserDN)
```

And always get O as result

Comment: VBScript only does BStr. It's the COM standard string.

Comment: Please show how you do the comparision. Also show sample values. Use `WScript.Echo` to verify that the values are actually what you think they are.

Comment: I have edit the code with the complete sample